# How do I auto refresh Google Chrome page on error?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, web

Is it possible to auto reload the page, when there is a network error?
For example when the server is down, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT page is visible. Can I automatize the reload in these cases?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724668/chrome-extension-to-reload-page-on-load-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Edge can use Chrome extensions, so I suggest using
[Auto Refresh Plus | Page Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-plus-page-mo/hgeljhfekpckiiplhkigfehkdpldcggm).

This extension lists among its capabilities
"Refresh Predefined Text Keywords".

You could then set it to refresh when the text includes the keyword
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.